# How to view DGN file in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcmap, dgn

I have a DGN file made by Workshop Paint Pro and would like to view it in ArcMap 10 so that I can create a risk map.

What are the procedures I need to follow?

Answer (score 4):

You may run into issues since you're not publishing the DGN file using MircoStation.

You need to allow ArcMap to read certain CAD formats. From the [ESRI Help](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001000000006000000):

> 1. Start ArcCatalog or ArcMap.
> 2. Click Customize on the main menu and click ArcCatalog Options or
>      ArcMap Options.
> 3. Click the CAD tab.
> 4. Check the box Examine all file extensions to display all DGN files.
>      Uncheck it to display only DGN files saved with the .dgn extension.
> 5. Click OK to close the dialog box.

[This page](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001000000004000000) shows the supported AutoCAD and MicroStation formats at the 10.1. Note:

> Direct-read formats are translated on the fly into memory as read-only
>   feature datasets. You can add them to map documents directly from the
>   Catalog window.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try with this tool, inside conversion toolbox:

http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00120000001z000000